# In XAML(WPF), why WrapPanel can be put inside FrameworkElementFactory directly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, desktop-application

In WPF, the items panel of **`ItemsControl`** such as **`ListBox`** can be replaced to layout items in different way. such as:

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <WrapPanel/>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

The code above works. But why **`WrapPanel`** can be put inside **`ItemsPanelTemplate`** directly? The **`ItemsPanelTemplate`** has a **`VisualTree`** property, which is inherited from **`FrameworkTemplate`** class. The **`VisualTree`** property is a content property, and is type of **`FrameworkElementFactory`**. So the code above really is:

```
<ListBox>
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate.VisualTree>
       <FrameworkElementFactory>
         <WrapPanel/>
       </FrameworkElementFactory>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate.VisualTree>
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Now, the question come here: The **`FrameworkElementFactory`** has no content property, and even has no properties of type **`Panel`**, so why **`WrapPanel`** can be put inside **`FrameworkElementFactory`** directly?

Comment: ItemsPanelTemplate works just the same as DataTemplate or ControlTemplate. I don’t think they actually use the VisualTree property, that is for programmatically creating templates (in C#). I believe XAML uses the TemplateContent property and quite a bit of internal code (and maybe just a bit of black magic) to make the templates work. Bottom line: you can put any FrameworkElement you like in a template definition.